# vtk java voxel rendering

Tags: java, vtk, voxel, voxels

**Hi Guys,**

does anyone knows, why this code in Java compiles,
but an Error appears:

```
"An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x5d05b377, pid=4576, tid=4888
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [vtkVolumeRendering.dll+0x2eb377]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Programme\eclipse-workspace\bachelorarbeit_01\hs_err_pid4576.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug."
```

Here is my java source code which I copied from a C++ code here: 
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.vtk.user/35844

```
import vtk.vtkImageData;
import vtk.vtkUnstructuredGrid;
import vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper;
import vtk.vtkActor;
import vtk.vtkRenderWindow;
import vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor;
import vtk.vtkRenderer;
import vtk.vtkPoints;
import vtk.vtkVolume;
import vtk.vtkVoxel;
import vtk.vtkDataSetTriangleFilter;
import vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridVolumeRayCastMapper;
import vtk.vtkPiecewiseFunction;
import vtk.vtkVolumeProperty;
import vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction;
import vtk.vtkExtractEdges;
import vtk.vtkDoubleArray;
import vtk.vtkCellData;

public class Visualizer {

    public Visualizer()
    {

        int nbVoxels = 3*3*3;
        int voxelSize = 1;

        vtkPoints voxelPoints = new vtkPoints();
        voxelPoints.SetNumberOfPoints(8*nbVoxels);
        voxelPoints.SetDataTypeToDouble();

        vtkUnstructuredGrid grid = new vtkUnstructuredGrid();
        grid.Allocate(nbVoxels, voxelSize);

        vtkVoxel voxel = new vtkVoxel();

        int count = 0;
        int posX = 0;
        int posY = 0;
        int posZ = 0;

        for ( int v=0; v<nbVoxels ; v++ )
        {
                voxelPoints.InsertPoint(count*8+0, posX, posY, posZ);
                voxelPoints.InsertPoint(count*8+1, posX+voxelSize,  posY, posZ);
                voxelPoints.InsertPoint(count*8+2, posX, posY+voxelSize, posZ);
                voxelPoints.InsertPoint(count*8+3, posX+voxelSize,  posY+voxelSize, posZ);
                voxelPoints.InsertPoint(count*8+4, posX, posY, posZ+voxelSize);
                voxelPoints.InsertPoint(count*8+5, posX+voxelSize, posY, posZ+voxelSize);
                voxelPoints.InsertPoint(count*8+6, posX, posY+voxelSize, posZ+voxelSize);
                voxelPoints.InsertPoint(count*8+7, posX+voxelSize, posY+voxelSize, posZ+voxelSize);

                voxel.GetPointIds().SetId(0, count*8+0);
                voxel.GetPointIds().SetId(1, count*8+1);
                voxel.GetPointIds().SetId(2, count*8+2);
                voxel.GetPointIds().SetId(3, count*8+3);
                voxel.GetPointIds().SetId(4, count*8+4);
                voxel.GetPointIds().SetId(5, count*8+5);
                voxel.GetPointIds().SetId(6, count*8+6);
                voxel.GetPointIds().SetId(7, count*8+7);

                grid.InsertNextCell(11, voxel.GetPointIds());

                count++;

                posX += voxelSize;
                if ( posX == 3*voxelSize )
                {
                        posX = 0;
                        posY += voxelSize;
                        if ( posY == 3*voxelSize )
                        {
                                posY = 0;
                                posZ += voxelSize;
                        }
                }
        }
        grid.SetPoints(voxelPoints);



      //extract edges from unstructured grid
        vtkExtractEdges edges = new vtkExtractEdges();
        edges.SetInput(grid);

        vtkPolyDataMapper gridMapper = new vtkPolyDataMapper();
        gridMapper.SetInput(edges.GetOutput());

        vtkActor gridActor = new vtkActor();
        gridActor.SetMapper(gridMapper);
        gridActor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.0,0.0,0.0);

        vtkDoubleArray colourPts = new vtkDoubleArray();
        for(int i=0; i < nbVoxels; i++)
                colourPts.InsertNextValue(i);

        vtkCellData cellData = grid.GetCellData();
        cellData.SetNumberOfTuples(nbVoxels);
        cellData.SetScalars(colourPts);

      //create a transfer function mapping scalar value to color
        vtkColorTransferFunction fColor = new vtkColorTransferFunction();

        for (int idx = 0; idx < nbVoxels; idx++)
        {
                        fColor.AddRGBPoint(colourPts.GetValue(idx),1, 0, 0);
        }

        vtkPiecewiseFunction fOpacity = new vtkPiecewiseFunction();
        fOpacity.AddPoint(0, 1);
        fOpacity.AddPoint(nbVoxels, 1);

        vtkVolumeProperty volProp = new vtkVolumeProperty();
        volProp.SetColor(fColor);
        volProp.SetScalarOpacity(fOpacity);

        vtkDataSetTriangleFilter filter = new vtkDataSetTriangleFilter();
        filter.SetInput(grid);

        vtkUnstructuredGridVolumeRayCastMapper vrcm = new vtkUnstructuredGridVolumeRayCastMapper();
        vrcm.SetInput(filter.GetOutput());

        vtkVolume volume = new vtkVolume();
        volume.SetMapper(vrcm);
        volume.SetProperty(volProp);

        vtkRenderer renderer = new vtkRenderer();
        vtkRenderWindow renderWindow = new vtkRenderWindow();
        renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer);

        vtkRenderWindowInteractor renderWindowInteractor = new vtkRenderWindowInteractor();
        renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

        renderer.AddActor(volume);
        renderer.AddActor(gridActor);
        renderer.SetBackground(1,1,1);
        //renderer.ResetCamera();

        renderWindow.Render();
        renderWindowInteractor.Start();     

    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

David

Comment: Anything helpful in `hs_err_pid4576.log`?

Answer (score 1):

the message

## The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.

should give you an indication that the error is happening outside of java so looking at the java code will most likely be of little help.

The typical cause of stack overflow (regardless of language) is a recursive call that never reaches a base case and hence never starts back tracking.  The reason for this is that each call to the method causes the return address (reference) to be placed on the stack, the more calls that are made the more return addresses are stored until there is no more space on the stack.

did a quick google for this happening in vtkVolumeRendering.dll at other times and [found this if it's any help.](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper-Problem-in-java-td1244838.html)

link here in case above didn't work :)

http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper-Problem-in-java-td1244838.html